# Is this a valid proof of $(A∧B’) ∧C↔(A∧C) ∧B’$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

So I am supposed to prove $(A∧B’) ∧C↔(A∧C) ∧B’$ using wffs and equivalence rules. I have never done such proof, and I want to check if my steps are correct. This assignment is only graded based off of completion, but I want to be sure I am understanding the concepts correctly. Thanks for all the help in advance.

```
 Prove
       (A∧B’) ∧C↔(A∧C) ∧B’
       (A∧B’) ∧C = P
       (A∧C) ∧B’ = Q

       1. (A∧B’)          hyp
       2. C               hyp
       3. (A∧C)           hyp
       4. B’              hyp
       5. A ,B’,C         1,2 sim
       6. P,Q             5,  sim
       7.  P∧S            6, con
       8.  S∧P            7, comm
       9. (P→Q)∧(Q→P)     7,8 equ
       10. P↔Q            9 equ
```

Comment: The left hand side = $A \land B' \land C = A \land C \land B'=(A \land C) \land B' =$ right hand side

Comment: @user137481 so simple yet so effective, haha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you post this answer to your question and then accept it. If not, the question stays unanswered and people looking for unanswered questions keep ending up here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't define $S$ anywhere, so I don't know how it ends up in 7 & 8!

But back up to the start.

$$\begin{align} (A \land B') \land C &\iff A\land (B' \land C) \tag{associativity}\\ \\
& \iff A \land (C \land B') \tag{commutativity}\\ \\
&\iff (A\land C) \land B' \tag{associativity}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is intuitive correct but you don't use the common propositional calculus rule set.

Answer (score 1):

I learned it this way.

For this:
$$(A \land B') \land C \leftrightarrow (A\land C)\land B' $$
You need to show \begin{align}(A \land B') \land C \rightarrow (A\land C)\land B'\tag{1} \end{align} and \begin{align}(A\land C)\land B'\rightarrow (A \land B') \land C\tag{2}\end{align}
First show (1):
Use conditional proof:

1. Assume $(A\land B')\land C$
2. With Simp1 and 1. you get $(A\land B')$
3. With Simp1 and 2. you get $A$
4. With Simp2 and 2. you get $B'$
5. With Simp2 and 1. you get $C$
6. With Kon, 3. and 5. you get $A\land C$
7. With Kon, 4. and 6 you get $(A\land C)\land B'$
8. With Conclusion of 1-7 you get $(A \land B') \land C \rightarrow (A\land C)\land B'$

Thus (1)

(2) can be proofen analogy
With (1) and (2) you get your equivalence!